# How to create a huggingface dataset and import from a list?

Tags: python, huggingface-datasets

I have a list and I want to convert it to a huggingface dataset for training model, I follow some tips and here is my code,

```
from datasets import Dataset
class MkqaChineseDataset(Dataset):

    def __init__(self, data):
       # super().__init__() if add this, it shows super().__init__() TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'arrow_table'
        self.data = data
        
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.data)
    
    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        sample = self.data[idx]
        return {
            "input_ids": sample["input_ids"], 
            "attention_mask": sample["attention_mask"],
            "labels":sample["input_ids"]
        }


buffer_test = [
    {'input_ids': torch.Tensor([9437,29,210]), 'attention_mask': torch.Tensor([1, 1, 1])},
    {'input_ids': torch.Tensor([37,9,211]), 'attention_mask':  torch.Tensor([1, 1, 1])},
    {'input_ids': torch.Tensor([937,19,212]), 'attention_mask': torch.Tensor([1, 1, 1])}
]
print(buffer_test)
mkqa = MkqaChineseDataset(buffer_test)
res = isinstance(mkqa, Dataset)
print(res)
```

However, it shows attributes error:

```
    self.data = data
AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

Comment: you need and arrow table to properly initialize your class, and you should used super and pass the correct argument. What you are doing has no much sense, since you completely overwrite the initializer. Is this question still an issue

Comment: @LucasM.Uriarte Thanks for your reply and totally approve, there is still some problems here, for example, it shows err if you `print(mkqa)` Could you please give more details of you suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Dataset.from_list` e.g. in your case

```py
buffer_test = [
    {'input_ids': torch.Tensor([9437,29,210]), 'attention_mask': torch.Tensor([1, 1, 1])},
    {'input_ids': torch.Tensor([37,9,211]), 'attention_mask':  torch.Tensor([1, 1, 1])},
    {'input_ids': torch.Tensor([937,19,212]), 'attention_mask': torch.Tensor([1, 1, 1])}
]

ds = Dataset.from_list(buffer_test)
```